# How To Remove The Automatic Text That Appears When A Cursor Hovers Over The Jumplink

Tags: html, css, blogger

I would like to remove the automatic text that appears when the cursor hovers over the jumplink. The text is usually the name of the post title that its directing to. However I would like to remove it. I've tried removing certain parts of the following code for the jumplink but to no avail. The coding is as follows:

```
<b:if cond='data:post.hasJumpLink'>
  <div class='jump-link'>
    <a expr:href='data:post.url + &quot;#more&quot;' expr:title='data:post.title'><data:post.jumpText/></a>
  </div>
</b:if>
```

Any help will be appreciated. The URL to the blog is as follows: http://www.blankesque.com

Answer (score 0):

The browser will show what is inside your title attribute automatically.

There is a good reason for that.

Sometimes you have an image on you web site and for any reason will not display or your site is loading to slowly.

In place of your image you than can see the value of the title attribute (or the alt attribute in very old browsers), so the user will not see a complete empty space

So if you can miss the title attribute just deleted or set his value to ="".

There are also other solutions for this, but seen you don't know much about attributes, seems to me not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `expr:title='data:post.title'` part from the `<a>` tag in the code.

```
<b:if cond='data:post.hasJumpLink'>
  <div class='jump-link'>
    <a expr:href='data:post.url + &quot;#more&quot;'><data:post.jumpText/></a>
  </div>
</b:if>
```

Answer (score -1):

I know you haven't got javascript tagged but I tried css and couldn't get a solution and the only way I found was JS, I'll keep trying though

```js
var links=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(i=0;i<links.length;i++){links[i].title="";}
```

```html
<a href="#" title="hello" class="show">this won't show the title</a><br><br>
<a href="#" title="hello" class="hide">This won't show the title</a>
```